# How to search lemma in Ruby's Words or Wordnet gems?

Tags: ruby, wordnet, lemmatization

The lexicon generated by both of these gems has entries for words like 'happen' or 'happy' but not 'happened' or 'happier'. I'd like to be able to search with 'happened' or 'happier' and return the synsets for 'happen' or 'happy'. I could download a lemmatizer to do this, but that seems wasteful to me considering Wordnet already has morphs for words (I know how to get 'happened' if I already have 'happen', for example, but I don't see how to go the other direction in the documentation).

A related question: Which of the gems, between words and wordnet, should I be using? What's the difference between them?

(I'm using this for a search bar that needs to find similar words to the query)